# arrays of type struct

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct

0i have declared a struct as follows:

```
struct node
    {
        int num;
        struct node *ptr;
    };

    typedef struct node NODE;
```

and i have a linked list with a pointer called first pointing to it.

and i have also declared an arraye of the above type NODE `NODE* array[312500];`

and now i want to make array[0] point to the linked list instead of first, so i have used  `array[0]->ptr=first;`

but this way gives me a segmentaion fault!!! what might be the problem!!!

Answer (score 4):

You declared an array of pointers, but never allocated memory for any of the pointers.

```
NODE* array[312500];
```

Is an array of 312500 pointers of type NODE*

If you wanted just `NODE`s, then say

```
NODE array[312500];
```

Else, you will need to say something like

```
array[0] = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

And then you can alter its `ptr`

Comment: array[0] = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
 array[0]->ptr=first;
is this right to do???

Comment: @TIMTAYLOR: Yes, that sounds right. Keep in mind that you will need to allocate memory for each element of your array if you want to use them, not just the first one. Also bear in mind that you should clean up that memory using `free` when you are finished with it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allocate memory to the array.
You just have an array of pointers.So  `array[0]->ptr` will give a segmentation fault.

Allocate memory to the array first :

```
for(i=0;i<312500;++i)
{
   array[i]=(NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
}
```

Or at least to `array[0]` by the same syntax to use `array[0]->ptr`.